# How to enable wekan (via snap) on my ubuntu server?

Tags: server, snap, wekan

I tried following the [wiki](https://github.com/wekan/wekan-snap/wiki) but it didn't help.

I would like to be able to point to mywebsite.url and have it load wekan.

Setting the url via the snap didn't do that. The Nextcloud snap (for instance) works just fine for this.

Comment: I think you should explain what wekan is. What exactly do you want to achieve, what did you try, and where did it fail?